# How do I require a function in a node modules without using a Module Bundler

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, es6-modules, commonjs

I cannot find an accurate answer to this anywhere. I understand the browser doesn't recognise commonJS syntax hence why if require() is loaded into the browser a reference error occurs like this

```
let isEven = require('is-even') // ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
console.log(isEven(6)); // this doesn't run
```

So I try to use ES6 modules like this:

```
import isEven from "is-even";
console.log(isEven(6));
```

I then get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Module specifier, 'is-even' does not start with "/", "./", or "../".
```

My fix at the moment is to run a module bundler like Webpack which allows me to use both of these syntax's effectively and I have no problems. However I would rather find an alternative because I find it harder to fix bugs when using a module bundler as it can be quite difficult to locate the code causing the error. Is there an alternative other than using a module bundler to transform to older Javascript modules before served to the browser ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243633/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-greetham-how-do-i-require-a-function-in-a-node-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` in a browser does not allow importing from a plain filename. You must at least construct some kind of path starting with `"/"`, `"./"`, or `"../"` or even a full URL as `import` in the browser does not have a "default" place to load a plain filename from. You must be explicit about what the path is.

And, keep in mind that `import` from a browser will make a request to your server and your server must be configured to provide that file to the browser when requested.

So, depending upon how you have your server configured, you may want something like this:

```
import isEven from "/is-even.js";
console.log(isEven(6));
```

Or, if your server handles scripts separately, you might even have this:

```
import isEven from "/scripts/is-even.js";
console.log(isEven(6));
```

And, then it is the web server's responsibility to know how to receive one of these requests, know where that actual script file is in the server's file system, get it and send it back to the browser.

---

Keep in mind that the main reason client-side code uses bundlers is that it is not efficient to have a web page that loads tons of script modules, each loaded separately because each script load is an http round-trip request to your server.  Loading can benefit some from client-side caching, but you still don't want your web-site's home page to have to load 50 separate modules the first time a user hits your home page just to get all your scripts loaded into the browser.

So, it would generally not be efficient in client-side code to import a script just for one function like `isEven()`.  This is why bundlers exist so that you can write the code in nice, modular, separately testable modules and then have the bundler go grab all the code that is needed for a particular client-side operation and collect it into one common script file that can then be loaded more efficiently into the client-side environment.

Comment: Your answer is great.  Do I need to specify the exact path in the node modules folder ? Is it common to just specify:  import isEven from "is-even" and let Webpack do its thing ?

Comment: @KevinGreetham - More info on the path of the file is in a comment under your question and added to my answer.  No, you will not use the node_modules folder path from the browser.  In client-side development, it is common to use a bundler where you would just do `import isEven from "is-even"` and let webPack do its thing.  That is what bundlers are for so you can do efficient modular coding, but end up with efficient client-side loading.

Comment: Good insight about why module bundlers are useful

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
export { isEven }; // module exports a function:
```

module imports the function from `is-even.mjs`

```
import { isEven } from './is-even.mjs';
console.log(is-even(6));
```

Comment: If I misunderstood the question, I'd appreciate the assistance.

Comment: I didn't mark you down, i must say tho your answer has confused me, could you eloborate ?

Comment: The OP is trying to use `import` in client-side code that runs in the browser.  There is no `require()` and there is no `__dirname` in the browser as both of those are nodejs constructs that work only in server-side code running in nodejs and even then only in CommonJS modules.

Comment: My apologies for not understanding the question, and thank you very much for your assistance, jfriend00.  and i hope you get your answer kevin